# Deploying using enterprise certificate has UI discrepancy

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise

Deploying an iOS application using an Enterprise certificate has UI elements missing, and/or attribute differences compared to deploying with a regular development certificate. Would anyone happen to know why this occurs? I have confirmed some images are not being copied and bundled with the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build to Archive or do Ad Hoc to Archive, **make sure that you set the Skip Install property to YES for Release builds**, *if you're using static linked libraries*.

Without this, any place you're using static linked libraries (i.e. #defines) could potentially be ignored.

This documentation explains that part of the process:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html

Answer (score 2):

- For any missing images, check the case of your image names.
- Do a full rebuild of your app (ie Build->Clean).
- Do a fuller rebuild - delete the "build" and simulator folders
- Make sure all of your NIBs and images are included in your enterprise target
- Try an Ad Hoc build

XCode itself can be a bit flaky. I've noticed some things fixed in 4.1 that are broken in 4.0.2, although the latest beta versions introduce their own bugs. That aside, blowing away the build folder forces the compiler to start over - ie, it forces the compiler to be consistent in ways that the IDE isn't written to handle.

Just because a file is included in the Project Navigator doesn't mean that it will be included in your project. Select the file and look in the "Target Membership" section of the File Inspector tab within the Utilities view (the right-side pane of XCode).

Some attributes don't work in IB. IB can be buggy. Plus there's some differences between the simulator and a device; testing a debug and ad hoc build on a device might help you uncover the issue.

I've sometimes had to blow away a distribution build and start over from scratch due to some weird behavior, like you're describing. An Ad Hoc build is a slightly different type of distribution, so creating a new distribution might somehow bypass whatever weird attribute got set for your Enterprise configuration.